# Vuejs check if cookie is set without page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies

What I want to do with VUE at the moment is when the user log in the `login url` would disappear from the navigation.

Currently, I can log in and `token cookie` is set successfully in the browser. But the problem is while I won't refresh my page the `login url` won't disappear from the navigation bar. Heres some code examples:

Login.vue sets the cookie and redirects me to `home` when I log in:

```
if(response.status === 200 && response.data.success && response.data.token) {
  const token = response.data.token;
  this.$cookie.set('token', token);
  this.$router.push({name: 'home'});
```

Then in `Navigation.vue` I check if the cookie exists:

```
<li class="nav-item" v-if="!cookie">
    <router-link class="nav-link" to="login">Login</router-link>
</li>  

data: () => {
    return {
        cookie: Vue.cookie.get('token')
    }
},
```

So the cookie exists after login but VUE understands that only after I hit the refresh button in browser or f5. How can I solve this so the `login url` disappears immediately after login?

This is my `axios` configuration:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' 
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ Vue.cookie.get('token');
      return config;
    },
    error => Promise.reject(error)
  );
```

**EDIT**

Maybe I can achieve something with VUEX?

**EDIT 2**

So currently this is my solution:
I've added VUEX so the token is set like this also:

```
  this.$cookie.set('token', token);
  this.$store.state.cookie = this.$cookie.get('token');
  this.$router.push({name: 'home'});
```

And in my `Navbar.vue` I do this:

```
computed: {
    cookie() {
        return this.$store.state.cookie
    }
},
```

and then check like this:

```
<span v-if="$cookie.get('token') || cookie">
    Log out
</span>
<span v-else>
    <router-link class="nav-link" to="login">Login</router-link>
</span>
```

`$cookie.get('token') || cookie` so the `cookie` is from VUEX which checks it without page refresh but after page refresh VUEX state is gone. So then after page refresh `$cookie.get('token')` works.

Comment: What do your `vue-router` settings look like?

Comment: @dexter I've updated my question with solution. Can you check it ?

Comment: I would check if the cookie exitst in `vue-router` and then do a redirect. You could use navigation guards for that (see [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)). In my app, I check the cookie and if it exists it always redirects me to `home`. You don't need `vuex` for that.

Comment: @dexter Problem is that `home` can view and guest and the logged in user. I would do that in router as you say if the `home` would be only for authenticated users.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you want to use some sort of event/signaling mechanism to inform different components about the change in a cookie value. Vuex is one mechanism to do that. Alternately, you can use Vue instance as an Event bus channel:

#### STEP 1: Create Event Bus using Vue in event.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const eventBus = new Vue();
```

#### STEP 2: Import it in `Login.vue` and publish an event when cookie is set:

```
import { eventBus } from './event.js';

// ... Other code
this.$cookie.set('token', token);

// Publish event
eventBus.$emit('tokenSet', token);
```

#### STEP 3: Listen to this event in `Navigation.vue`:

```
import { eventBus } from './event.js';



data() {
    return {
        cookie: Vue.cookie.get('token')
    }
},

created() {
    eventBus.$on('tokenSet', (token) => this.cookie = token);
}
```

This way your cookie becomes reactive by updating whenever `tokenSet` event is fired. With this, you really don't need to refresh the page and even if refreshed, the initial value of the cookie is read by the `data` function. In a large-scale application, something like Vuex or Redux is a way to go but the underlying idea is still the same.

For more details refer to [this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/).